# Get an object that angularJS renders into HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a website that is built with angularJS, and I am interested enough to ask: is it possible to get an object that angularJS renders its values into the HTML. Here, let me be more concrete.

[image]

Here, there is a big `search` object that has lots of properties, one of them is `projects` that is a list, and `ng-repeat` use it to iterate over them and present the values from there.

My question is, is it possible to get that `search` object to see full containing of it (maybe console log it)?

I have to note that I have no source code for this website, I am only using it as a regular user.

Comment: try ctrl+u , you'll get the source code. if its not minified, put a debugger over that line from `sources` tab of dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be the angular inspector plugin for Chrome. With it installed, inspect the element. To the right side of the "Elements" tab, there is the styles box, you should also see "computed" and the "angularJS Properties" tab added by the extension. Select the AngularJs Properties.

Scroll down unlit you see the search object.
[image: This is an example from another AngularJs site]

Another option to see it in the console:
Select the item with the inspector, then use 
`angular.element($0).scope()`
to view the scope of the element. The search object should be there.

Third option, similar to above, use the following to access the element's Scope:
`angular.element(document.getElementById('yourElementId')).scope()`
Of course you can use any method to select the element.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. I have used all of your methods and the problem is that the methods always returns `undefined` values when I try to inspect them. Probably a website has some kind of protection in there and/or cleans the object, so people can't inspect anything in there.